# Invalid key length node.js triple DES encrpytion

Tags: c#, node.js, encryption, cryptography, tripledes

```
var tripleDES = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
var sha1 = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();

var keyBytes = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(key);
var hashKey = sha1.ComputeHash(keyBytes);
System.Array.Resize(ref hashKey, ((tripleDES.KeySize / 8)));
tripleDES.Key = hashKey;
```

I am new to node.js and am trying to switch the encryption from c# to node.js but it gives an error of `Invalid key length 22` below is the node.js code.

```
var text = "test";
var des_key = new Buffer("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv",'utf8');
var des_iv = new Buffer(0);

var des_decryption = crypto.createCipheriv("DES-EDE3", des_key, des_iv);
var test = des_decryption.update(text,'utf8','base64');
test+=des_decryption.final('base64')
console.log("test:"+test)
```

I have edited the code below to show the correct code

```
var text = "test";
var des_key = new Buffer("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv",'base64');
var des_iv = new Buffer(IV,'base64');

var des_decryption = crypto.createCipheriv("DES-EDE3-CBC", des_key, des_iv);
var test = des_decryption.update(text,'ucs2','base64'); //ucs2 is the same as utf16
test+=des_decryption.final('base64')
console.log("test:"+test)
```

Comment: Well, it seems you forgot to hash your "key" before use with SHA-1 in node.js.

Comment: Furthermore, don't forget to transport the random IV from C# to node.js.

Comment: what do you mean by transport the random IV?

Comment: @ArtjomB. After I use hash, it works but the encrypted output is different from the c# code. node.js: eiw7XmQOYGo= c#: i14HzuoyWokHK1VwzkI1ZQ==

Comment: If you're using `TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider`, the default is CBC mode, which needs an IV and is automatically randomly generated. You have to use the same IV during decryption, so you must transport it along with the ciphertext. Also, `DES-EDE3` in node.js probably uses ECB mode and not CBC mode, you would have to use `DES-EDE3-CBC`

Comment: @ArtjomB. Thanks for the help, I found out another error with my code. The Encoding.Unicode reads as utf16 but I am using utf8 in my node.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely this is caused by unmatching [key-length](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.tripledes.key(v=vs.110).aspx). Triple DES expect key length of `128-bit` or `192-bit` depending on its [KeySize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.tripledes.key(v=vs.110).aspx) setting. Thus, you must supply either `16 bytes` key for `128-bit` or `24 bytes` for `192-bit`.

Here, your error shows that you supply the `Triple DES` Key with `22 bytes` key length:

> Invalid key length 22

which won't be acceptable in either case.

Check your `tripleDES.KeySize`. If it is `128`, ensure that your `hashKey` is 16 bytes length and if it is `192`, ensure your `hashKey` is `24-bytes` length.

Comment: the keysize is 192 but I use the same key for the c# code it works, so it should work on node.js too isn't it?

Comment: @Dylan may not be the case, seeing your `node.js`: `var des_key = new Buffer("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv",'utf8');` it is only 22 bytes... unfortunately

Comment: I tried changing the des_key to `new Buffer("Gk7XHvGStyzIuoGsZ9OZeJ1E0mQAAAAA", 'base64')` which i get from the encryption of the key in c# and the function works, but the encrypted output is different from the c# code

Comment: @Dylan DES is quite complex... could it be due to different IV used?

Comment: from what I know des doesn't take in a iv that is why I initiate with Buffer(0)

Comment: @Dylan It is hard for me to tell what is the problem at this point... but having the resources to test, you may want to further debug to see if you can find further clue..

Comment: Thanks, I'll post another question to why it give different output

Comment: @Dylan Don't post another question. Try to solve it yourself first. I've given you a lot of clues.

Comment: @Dylan check [this](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5333/difference-between-stream-cipher-and-block-cipher) it explains about different block streaming which you may want to know

Comment: @ArtjomB. I gave a link explaining about that from different post in SE. :) maybe he can take a look on that